# Ajaxplorer - Open files in editor

Tags: editor, text-editor, mime, file-manager, pydio

I have a simple problem in using the editor. I need to be able to open any file type with ajaxplorer text editor (ex: .ini files,).

When I click on a file with extension .php an icon appears in the bar that says (open with) and I'm able to edit the file or view it online. However, when I click a file with a extension (.ini) the icon disappears and I can't view or edit it online.

Is there a way to make all files that aren't recognized open by default in the text editor ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of Ajaxplorer solves this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
in the `editor.text` replace

```
mimes="none"
```

to

```
mimes="*"
```